# What's this logkit, and why is it taking screenshots?

Tags: applications, screenshots

I'm using android 4.0.4.

I suddenly saw this notification in my notification pane:
[image: Logkit notification]

This has happened a few times already. Tapping on the notification removes it immediately.

The screenshot is indeed in the location specified. However, I never pressed anything to activate the screenshot (at least, I don't think I did.)

I can't find a LogKit app in my application menu either. The symbol looks like the qualcomm symbol though.

What's this LogKit? Is it a virus? Or is it some hidden system application? Is this app automatically taking screenshots something I should be worried about?

Comment: AFAIK, it's a logging app to help app developers debug their apps. I have seen this when using 1 particular app on older version, but no more screenshot on the latest version (hopefully since they realized the mistake of releasing an app with active debugging tool). I'd say it's safe, it's not a virus. While I'm unsure if this is the same app, [ForeSafe says that it's safe](http://www.foresafe.com/report/FBE5A6CFAB7E3A623D43CF29F88C8490)